# jQuery: How to select a child or element with attribute that contains x?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Let's say I have some unordered lists with items, and one or many that has a class of 'active'

```
<ul id='list'>
  <li class='row active'></li>
  <li attrA='something active'></li>
  <li attrB='active'></li>
</ul>

<ul id='otherList'>
  <li class='row active'></li>
  <li attrA='something active'></li>
  <li attrB='active'></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the item where class is "active" that is a child or element of the unordered list, "list".

I tried...

- `$("#list li[class~='active']")`
- `$("#list > li[class~='active']")`

But to no avail...

Here's a more detailed version of my problem. The code used to print this output is...

1. `var listId = "typeahead-3-6260";`
2. `console.log( $("#"+listId+" li") );`
3. `console.log( $("#"+listId+" li[class~='active']") );`

As you can see, line 2 had some results, but line 3 didn't.

[image: Pic]

Comment: what is `attrA` and `attrB` ..? confused after seeing that..

Comment: If you're looking for just the `class` attribute, then what you have should already work, particularly if any of the answers below that use the class selector do work for you...

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry, 'name' was a typo in this question. In my file, it's 'class'. And 'x' is just a string that could be anything, in this case, 'active'.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy attrA or attrB are just random attributes, could have been anything. I had a reason for it, but I guess it doesn't matter now.

Comment: @user3228667 Then you can have a look at my answer..

Comment: Any chance you could reproduce this on http://jsfiddle.net? Something else must be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#list li").filter(function(){return $(this).attr('name').indexOf("name") >= 0)
```

Comment: Note, this can be simply rewritten as `$('#list li[name*="name"]')`.

Comment: What could be wrong? I tried that code out, but all I'm getting back an empty object. Oddly enough, `$('#list li')` works...

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.attributes` to get the list of attributes and use `nodeValue` to get the value of attribute to check if it has `active`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kD8u2/1/)**

```
$("#list li").each(function(){   
  for(i=0; i < this.attributes.length; i++)
     if(this.attributes[i].nodeValue.indexOf('active') != -1)
         $(this).text('has active attribute');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you need to check the 'class' attribute as 'active' here is the code that might help you

```
$(document).on('click','#list>li.active',function(){
    alert('I am here');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8eDz/)